# Issue regarding Java to XML conversion and vice versa

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, xml-parsing, xml-binding

I have XML like this which I get from middleware

```
<Example library="somewhere">

   <book>

     <AUTHORS_TEST>Author_Name</AUTHORS_TEST>
     <EXAMPLE_TEST>Author_Name</EXAMPLE_TEST>

   </book>

</Example>
```

What I want to do is  convert the XML to Java object(and Vice Versa) as:

```
class Example
 {

 private String authorsTest;
 private String exampleTest;

  }
```

So Is there any way to map these two,The thing to be noted is that XML Tag Name and the Class attribute name is different,So can anyone suggest to implement this with minimal changes?Xstream is a good Choice,but if I have large number of fields it will be difficult to add aliases,so any better choices other than XStream?

Comment: Use JAXB, it's now standard in JDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

Most XML-binding libraries require an object per level of nesting in the XML representation.  EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) has the `@XmlPath` extension that enables XPath based mapping to remove this restriction.

**Example**

Below is a demonstration of how the `@XmlPath` extension can be applied to your use case.

```
package forum10511601;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement(name="Example")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Example {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String library;

    @XmlPath("book/AUTHORS_TEST/text()")
    private String authorsTest;

    @XmlPath("book/EXAMPLE_TEST/text()")
    private String exampleTest;

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

To specify MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to add a file named `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry (see [Specifying EclipseLink MOXy as Your JAXB Provider](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html)).

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**Demo**

As MOXy is a JAXB (JSR-222) implementation, you use the standard JAXB runtime APIs (which are included in the JRE/JDK starting with Java SE 6).

```
package forum10511601;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Example.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum10511601/input.xml");
        Example example = (Example) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(example, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Example library="somewhere">
   <book>
      <AUTHORS_TEST>Author_Name</AUTHORS_TEST>
      <EXAMPLE_TEST>Author_Name</EXAMPLE_TEST>
   </book>
</Example>
```

Comment: ,Thanks for the Implementation

Comment: Is there any way to convert the XML O/P  to Java Object using MOXy as your JAXB provider?

Comment: @Prebhathkesav - I'm not sure I understand your follow up question.  I believe the XML in my answer matches the XML.  One difference is the missing library attribute.  Should that correspond to a property in your domain object or something else?

Comment: Yes,it matches the XML and library attribute corresponds to a property

Comment: @Prabhathkesav - I've updated my answer to include the library attribute.  Please let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 3):

There are good libraries which does this for you. An easy one is [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) for example.

See this example from the [*Two Minute Tutorial*](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html):

```
Person joe = new Person("Joe", "Walnes");
joe.setPhone(new PhoneNumber(123, "1234-456"));
joe.setFax(new PhoneNumber(123, "9999-999"));
```

Now, to convert it to XML, all you have to do is make a simple call to XStream:

```
String xml = xstream.toXML(joe);
```

The resulting XML looks like this:

```
<person>
  <firstname>Joe</firstname>
  <lastname>Walnes</lastname>
  <phone>
    <code>123</code>
    <number>1234-456</number>
  </phone>
  <fax>
    <code>123</code>
    <number>9999-999</number>
  </fax>
</person>
```

I would prefer XStream because it is very easy to use. If you want to do more complex things like generating Java classes from the XML you should have a look at [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/) as Miquel mentioned. But it is more complex and needs more time to get started.

Comment: Will XStream be helpful to map the different XML Tag Name and Class attribute name?

Comment: Yes, you can define `@XStreamAlias`es for this.

Comment: Note that the original question is about turning an xml document into a class, not the other way around. Also, by the way, what you have up there is not a schema, but an xml document.

Comment: @Miquel: XStream can do both! _"XStream is a simple library to serialize objects to XML and back again."_

Comment: Thanks @ user714965, I have gone through it and its very helpful,but otherthan Xstream,Can we do in minimal changes other than this?

Comment: Xstream is a good Choice,but if I have large number of fields it will be difficult to add aliases,so any better choices?

Comment: You could generate new Objects which variables are named like the elements in the XML (by JAXB). But then you surely have to make changes on other parts of your code. So you have to make this mapping, there is no way around.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is called XML Binding, where you actually turn an xml into a java class based on an xml schema. The reference implementation for this is [jaxb](http://jaxb.java.net/) but there are many other alternatives.